# How to connect keyboard arrows with robotino sim and view?

Tags: c#, mqtt, robotics

So I have a project to do, which is to connect a Robotino view with a Robotino Sim, and also connect to a C# client program to **move the Robotino in the View with the arrows on the keyboard**.

The C# client is supposed to send the data about pressing the arrow buttons 4 times per second through cloud MQTT.

So far I connected the View with the Sim, added some basic navigator ( on which you click and the robot moves), but I have no idea how to do the rest.

I also found this cloud MQTT .Net thingy, but it just doesn't speak to me.
https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-dotnet.html

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this issue, since I found nothing really useful, only this video (basically that is what I want to do ), which has no description but the project is working for him.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmKyFNLWv_A&t=11s

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't work this way. You have to try yourself, then when you get stuck, you show us what you have done, explain how it doesn't work and somebody will help you fix it.

Comment: I see, sorry for toubling you then. :)